# DataTables footerCallback and contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, contenteditable

I have a DataTable that sums over each column using footerCallback. This works perfectly given the data in each column, but I also want to add the ability to change each cell's value that is being summed. I've tried adding "contenteditable" to those cells, but making a change does not affect the sum in the footer.

Here is a simple jsfiddle showing the behavior I'm experiencing: https://jsfiddle.net/rantoun/552y9j90/6/

HTML:

```
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Fruit</th>
      <th># Eaten</th>
      <th># Remaining</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th align="right">Count</th>
      <th align="left"></th>
      <th align="left"></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Apples</td>
      <td contenteditable>3</td>
      <td contenteditable>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Oranges</td>
      <td contenteditable>6</td>
      <td contenteditable>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bananas</td>
      <td contenteditable>2</td>
      <td contenteditable>9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#table1").DataTable({
  "paging": false,
  "searching": false,
  "info": false,    
    "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {

      var columns = [1, 2];
      var api = this.api();

      _.each(columns, function(idx) {

          var total = api
              .column(idx)
              .data()
              .reduce(function (a, b) {
                  return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
              }, 0)         

                $('tr:eq(0) th:eq('+idx+')', api.table().footer()).html(total);
      })

  }
});
```

I have also found the DataTables editor (https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple), which would be perfect for this situation - but it is not open source. Any ideas on how to mimic this **inline editing** functionality is welcome. I would like to avoid doing this with modals. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: basically, what I did was add an on click event handler that when you clicked on a cell, it would change the cell to a text box to let my user to enter the info. I used the on blur event handler to update the datatable data object and convert it back to a regular table cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer that allows you to edit in place with contenteditable.

Note that this requires the [dataTables KeyTable plugin](https://datatables.net/extensions/keytable/)

[Working Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8w99kt93/)

```
/* Note - requires datatable.keys plugin */
    var table = $("#table1").DataTable({

      "keys": true,     

      "paging": false,
      "searching": false,
      "info": false,    
        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {

          var columns = [1, 2];
          var api = this.api();

          _.each(columns, function(idx) {

              var total = api
                  .column(idx)
                  .data()
                  .reduce(function (a, b) {
                      return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
                  }, 0)         

                    $('tr:eq(0) th:eq('+idx+')', api.table().footer()).html(total);
          })

      }
    });

    // keys introduces the key-blur event where we can detect moving off a cell
    table
        .on( 'key-blur', function ( e, datatable, cell ) {

        // The magic part - using the cell object, get the HTML node value,
        // put it into the dt cell cache and redraw the table to invoke the 
        // footer function. 
            cell.data( $(cell.node()).html() ).draw()
        } );
```

Note - I can foresee that you may get non-numeric data entered. You will have to police that in the key-blur event where you can test the dom node value and act accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! Quick and easy to implement - works perfectly

Comment: DataTables is a realy powerful, pragmatic and well-thought-out piece of work and I have not yet found it lacking. Thanks.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat I want to use this method in a button, can you helop me ?